# jQuery confirm box

Tags: php, jquery

I have a loop that runs through checking boxes for input, if everything returns okay, it needs to show a popup box asking the user if it is okay to carry on and submit their order, and if not then it needs to do nothing (handled within)

I've come across a few problems and can't figure out how to do it, any ideas?

Here's my current code

```
    function validateSubmit(){
        var r=true;

       $('tr').each( function() {
          // Find first input
          var input1 = $(this).find('input').eq(0);
          var qty1 = input1.val();
          // Find Second input
          var input2 = $(this).find('input').eq(1);
          var qty2 = input2.val();
          // Find third input
          var input3 = $(this).find('input').eq(2);
          var qty3 = input3.val();
          // Find select box
          var selectBx = $(this).find('select');
          var selectVal = selectBx.val();
            if(qty1 === '' && selectVal != 'Please Select...') {
                alert("You've chosen an option, but not entered a quantity to dispute, please check your inputs.");
                r=false;return false;           
            }
            if(qty1 != '' && selectVal === 'Please Select...') {
                alert("You've entered a quantity, but not chosen why, please check your reasons.");
                r=false;return false;       
            }
            if (qty1 > qty2) {
                alert("For one of your entries, the disputed quantity is larger than the shipped quantity.");
                r=false;return false;               
            }
       }); 
           if (r==true) {
            var a = confirm("Are you sure you want to confirm the dispute? You cannot edit this after it's been submitted?");
            if (a==true)
            {
                return true;        
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
}

    });
```

HTML:

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>Item ID</th><th>Description</th><th>Dispute Quantity</th><th>Shipped Quantity</th><th>Ordered Quantity</th><th>Reason</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `artran09` WHERE `invno` = '$invoiceno'") or die(mysql_error());
                        echo "<center>";
                        $i = -1;        
                        echo "<form action=\"submitdispute.php?invno=".$invoiceno."&ordate=".$placed."\" method=\"POST\" onsubmit=\"return validateSubmit();\">";

                            while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {              
                                $i += 1;                                    
                                echo "<tr>"; 
                                echo "<td>".$info['item']."</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>".$info['descrip']."</td>";       

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" input name=".$i." onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\"  maxLength=\"3\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=".$info['qtyshp']." name = \"ship$i\" onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\" maxLength=\"3\" disabled=\"disabled\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=".$info['qtyord']." onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\" maxLength=\"3\" disabled=\"disabled\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><select name = \"reason$i\">";
                                echo "<option>Please Select...</option>";
                                echo "<option>Short/Not received</option>";
                                echo "<option>Damaged Goods</option>";
                                echo "<option>Product Not Ordered</option>";                    
                                echo "</select></td>";

                                echo "</tr>"; 
                            }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Dispute" name ="Submit">
    </form>
```

For anyone interested - I have fixed this!
Thank you for everyone's patience! Here's the fix:

```
   function validateSubmit(){
    var r=true;

   $('tr').each( function() {
      // Find first input
      var input1 = $(this).find('input').eq(0);
      var qty1 = input1.val();
      // Find Second input
      var input2 = $(this).find('input').eq(1);
      var qty2 = input2.val();
      // Find third input
      var input3 = $(this).find('input').eq(2);
      var qty3 = input3.val();
      // Find select box
      var selectBx = $(this).find('select');
      var selectVal = selectBx.val();
        if(qty1 === '' && selectVal != 'Please Select...') {
            alert("You've chosen an option, but not entered a quantity to dispute, please check your inputs.");
            r=false;return false;           
        }
        if(qty1 != '' && selectVal === 'Please Select...') {
            alert("You've entered a quantity, but not chosen why, please check your reasons.");
            r=false;return false;       
        }
        if (qty1 > qty2) {
            alert("For one of your entries, the disputed quantity is larger than the shipped quantity.");
            r=false;return false;           
        }
   }); 

    if (r=true) {
        var a = confirm("Are you sure you wish to dispute? You cannot dispute this order again once submitted.");
        return a;       
    }
}
```

Help massively appreciated!

Comment: Well, a quick glance would indicate that your nested if (a == true) and else statements contain additional confirms that you don't need.  Instead, you should be making a call to save your information.  In its current state, your code is very incomplete.  What would you like to do upon the user confirming that they are sure?

Comment: Oops sorry!!! I'll quickly edit that, I was just messing around and trying to get some sort of output from it! (Edited now)

Comment: That looks better :).  Now, you are either returning true or false.  So what are you doing with that response?  What are the "few problems" that you've been running into?

Comment: The problem i've been running into is that it doesn't seem to show at all, whether it returns any variables or not?

Comment: Anything showing in your error console?  Please setup a sample on jsfiddle with the related HTML markup.

Comment: What isn't showing?  The confirm box?  Have you debugged your script with a browser?

Comment: Also, post how you have actually called this function.

Comment: still not returning `r` from the main function. Suggest removing the `confirm` and get `validateSubmit()` working without it first. Need `return r` at end

Comment: I've edited in the HTML where it's called, hopefully that should give some guidance, i've also tried constructing it on jsfiddle and it won't return anything even when i just post the raw code

Comment: Also `confirm` shouldn't be displayed unless `r` is true

Comment: I've also edited in the r return, that should be visible now

Comment: don't post php...post live html...then all of this can be simply tesetd in jsfiddle.net. Copy html from browser and put a demo together...will save you and others a lot of time

Comment: I think it's all on there, that's the HTML echoed out from PHP along with the jQuery and there's no CSS used

Comment: we aren't php parsers to use the php as source html for a test... it takes seconds to get the real code browser sees and that javascript runs on

Comment: Okay, hang on! I'll switch it over

Comment: That isn't the generated HTML.

Comment: That's not from the browser, you've just removed the PHP code from your PHP, obvious by the escape characters you didn't remove. The above commenters are trying to help. If you don't do what they specifically ask you won't get anywhere fast.

Comment: open browser source view... html is all right there

Comment: I did that in the end, but I managed to figure it out myself! It's almost 3am here in the UK and I guess i'm getting tired haha! It turned out all I needed to do was get a confirm box to popup, assign it a variable
(for example: var a = confirm("String");)
Then return it out, if the user clicked cancel it returns false, if the user clicks OK it returns true

Thank you for your patience/help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
    function validateSubmit(){
    var r=true;

   $('tr').each( function() {
      // Find first input
      var input1 = $(this).find('input').eq(0);
      var qty1 = input1.val();
      // Find Second input
      var input2 = $(this).find('input').eq(1);
      var qty2 = input2.val();
      // Find third input
      var input3 = $(this).find('input').eq(2);
      var qty3 = input3.val();
      // Find select box
      var selectBx = $(this).find('select');
      var selectVal = selectBx.val();
        if(qty1 === '' && selectVal != 'Please Select...') {
            alert("You've chosen an option, but not entered a quantity to dispute, please check your inputs.");
            r=false;return false;           
        }
        if(qty1 != '' && selectVal === 'Please Select...') {
            alert("You've entered a quantity, but not chosen why, please check your reasons.");
            r=false;return false;       
        }
        if (qty1 > qty2) {
            alert("For one of your entries, the disputed quantity is larger than the shipped quantity.");
            r=false;return false;           
        }
   }); 

    if (r=true) {
        var a = confirm("Are you sure you wish to dispute? You cannot dispute this order again once submitted.");
        return a;       
    }
}
```